# Register mapping in a ARM based SoC

Tags: arm, microcontroller

I want to understand how the registers of various peripherals/IPs are mapped to the ARM processor memory map in a microcontroller.

Say, I have a CONTROL register for UART block. When I do a write access to address (40005008), this register gets configured. Where does this mapping happens: Within the peripheral block code itself or while integrating this peripheral to the SoC/microcontroller.

Comment: I think it happens in both, some lower port of the address bits is defined by peripheral block design and higher part of the address is set by SoC designers.

Comment: Generally this is how SoC specs mentions peripheral configurations as well. However I don't know if you wanted to hear some more details. In that case some other part of the stackexchange community (like electronics) might help you.

Comment: thanks auselen...  in continuity to your reply.. are the lower bits hard coded in the design code of the peripheral.. And depending on which memory region of the SoC we want to plug-in our peripheral, we decide the higher-bits in the bridge-address-decoders ??

Comment: Being fixed might be up to peripheral - probably to ease the design, but I don't have any idea about other parts. I don't think even programmers down to a certain level care or has knowledge about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple peripheral like a UART it's straightforward - taking the ARM PL011 UART as an example (since I know where its documentation lives):

The [programmer's model](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0183g/I18381.html) defines a bunch of registers at word-aligned *offsets* in a 4k block.

In terms of [the actual hardware](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0183g/I5112.html), we see the bus interface matches what the programmer's model suggests - PADDR[11:2] means only bits 11:2 of the address are connected, meaning it can only understand word-aligned addresses from 0x000 to 0xffc (similarly, note that only 16 bits of read/write data are connected, since no register is wider than that).

The memory-mapping between the UART's 12-bit address and the full 32-bit address that the CPU core spits out happens in the interconnect hardware between them. At design time, the interconnect address map will be configured to say "this 4k region at 0x40005000 is assigned to the UART0 block", etc., and the resulting bus circuitry will be generated for that.

More complex things like e.g. DMA-capable devices typically have separate interfaces for configuration and data access, so the registers can be mapped in a small relocatable block on a low-speed peripheral bus much like the UART.

Answer (score 1):

Most significant bits are defined by your ASIC design, least significant bits are defined by the IP design. Your IP has several registers. The number of register, their order, is defined by the IP design. Here, your register is at address 8. Then when designing the ASIC, the peripherals are connected to the memory bus, and the way they are connected define their address. Your UART is at 40005000. You may have an other instance of the same IP at (for instance) 40006000. The two UART would be strictly identical, and you would be able to access CONTROL register of your second UART at address 40006008.

Comment: Please add [AMBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Microcontroller_Bus_Architecture) as a reference.  AXI/AHB will be his top level bus.  Typically, the high level address bits route to a sub-bus.  For instance, the CPU connects to AXI or AHB.  Certain high level address bits route to an APB bus, which then routes to the IP by decoding middle address bits.  Then the lowest address bits select the registers.  The BUS is a tree. (as you said +1).  See also: [MUX/DEMUX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer) for the low-level hardware that routes.